# Presenting results from a regression with several lags of several independant variables

Tags: time-series, lags, tables, presentation

I have an OLS regression with several independent variables lagged several times. This means I have many coefficients and standard errors to present, making up a lot of rows in a table. A standard nice statistics table with around 30 rows takes up 2½ pages which is not an optimal way of presenting my results.

I could choose to leave the results for the controlling variables in the appendix but that would still leave ~15 rows which needs presenting which is over one page.

So I'm wondering if there's anything I'm missing about the presentation. I don't believe it's common practice to only present the variables that are significant or reach statistical significance. Is there a way to consolidate the standard error and coefficients of lags into 1 number?

The only way I can think of now to present my findings is to only present the standard error and coefficients for the lags that are statistically significant (since not a lot of them are). But that would look very unsystematical and arbitrary since it would just be a selection of different lags and variables.

Comment: Can you remove those lagged variables that are not statistically significant from your model to see if the model can be improved? This way you might be able to present a simpler model.